# How to disable Redis health check when redis-lettuce is integrated with micronaut

Tags: redis, micronaut

I have used this jar to integrate redis with micronaut.
**compile 'io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-redis-lettuce'**
By default, the redis health check is enabled even though i have disabled the health end point in my micronaut application.
https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-redis/latest/guide/

Below is the exception I am getting for every 100 seconds since I have configured the health interval as
**micronaut.health.monitor.interval: 100s**

````
Path Taken: new HealthMonitorTask(CurrentHealthStatus currentHealthStatus,[List healthIndicators]) --> new RedisHealthIndicator(BeanContext beanContext,[HealthAggregator healthAggregator],StatefulRedisConnection[] connections)
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [healthAggregator] of class: io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.health.RedisHealthIndicator

Message: No bean of type [io.micronaut.management.health.aggregator.HealthAggregator] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Path Taken: new HealthMonitorTask(CurrentHealthStatus currentHealthStatus,[List healthIndicators]) --> new RedisHealthIndicator(BeanContext beanContext,[HealthAggregator healthAggregator],StatefulRedisConnection[] connections)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:990)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.health.$RedisHealthIndicatorDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1494)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.addCandidateToList(DefaultBeanContext.java:2507)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfTypeInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2429)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:854)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.lambda$getBeansOfTypeForConstructorArgument$10(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1088)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanWithGenericsFromConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1697)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeansOfTypeForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1083)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:962)```
````

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
redis.health.enabled: false
```

Answer (score -1):

Setting this parameter as false in application.properties solved it.
`micronaut.health.monitor.enabled=false`

Comment: This would likely stop health monitor to check for all connections including Redis. How would you specifically disable redis health check